# PuppeteerSharp - anyone knows why it is always triggering reCaptcha?

Tags: recaptcha, puppeteer-sharp

I am trying to get data from one page, but I need to log in first. When using Puppeteer I am always stuck with reCaptcha. No matter if I use headless or not (it took me a while to figure out it was captcha as it was not rendered correctly).
When I manually log in using Chrome on the same machine, captcha is not displayed and I can log in. Also works if I use CefSharp.ChromiumWebBrowser.

I could not find any specific answer, but if someone's been there and it is a lost cause, please let me know. I cannot use any alternative here, so ChromiumWebBrowser will be my choice then.

Here is part of my code:

```
        browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions { Headless = true, ExecutablePath = @"c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", UserDataDir = @"C:/Users/XXXX/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/" });
        page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
        await page.SetViewportAsync(new ViewPortOptions() { IsMobile = false });
        await page.SetUserAgentAsync("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36");

        await page.GoToAsync(pUrl);
        await page.WaitForXPathAsync(pWaitingExpression);

        var cookies = await GetElementValue(null, "//button[@id='xyz']", false);

        if (cookies != null)
        {
            await page.EvaluateExpressionAsync("document.getElementById('xyz').click();");
        }

        var loginNode = await GetElementValue(null, "//span[@id='XXX']", false);

        if (loginNode != null)
        {
            await page.EvaluateExpressionAsync("document.getElementById('XXX').click();");
            await page.WaitForXPathAsync("//div[@id='XXX']");
            await page.EvaluateExpressionAsync("document.getElementById('XXX').value = 'XXXX';");
            await page.EvaluateExpressionAsync("document.getElementById('XXX').value = 'XXXXX';");
            await page.EvaluateExpressionAsync("document.evaluate('//div[@id=\"XXX\"]/input[@type=\"submit\"]', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.click();");
            await page.WaitForXPathAsync("//div[@id='ZZX']");
        }
```

UPDATE:

I think I know the reason why I am getting captcha in this particular case, but not the others. In non-headless mode I see following information below address bar - "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software". Based on this I followed up my research and found this page.
[https://intoli.com/blog/not-possible-to-block-chrome-headless/][1]
I included following code before navigating to my url:

```
                    await page.EvaluateExpressionOnNewDocumentAsync("Object.defineProperty(navigator,'webdriver', { get: () => false, });");
```

Unfortunately still no luck. I can see that text blinks before loading page, which indicates that property is reset, but then immediately changed back.

So I believe I answered original question - WHY, but now I need answer HOW to bypass that. Anyone knows?

Answer (score 0):

I answered this myself after some more research - PuppeteerExtraSharp.

```
puppeteerExtra = new PuppeteerExtra();
stealth = new PuppeteerExtraSharp.Plugins.ExtraStealth.StealthPlugin();
puppeteerExtra.Use(stealth);
browser = await puppeteerExtra.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions { Headless = false, ExecutablePath = @"c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" });
```

In case someone like me has already PuppeterSharp added to the project - it seems Extra requires lower level of original.